# How can i make this work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can i make this works?

I have 2 tables:

course:
course id,name
prereq:
course id,prereq id

What is the query for this result:

```
+----------+------------+----------+------------+
|Course ID |Name        |Prereq ID |Prereq Name |
|1         |Intro into B|          |            |
|2         |Biology     |1         |Intro into B|
|3         |Genetics    |1         |Intro into B|
+----------+------------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: Try indenting the table so that the page automatically recognizes it a code.  you can preview to make sure you got it right.  That will help people read your question.

Comment: but the prereq name on the first row is still showing Intro into B

Comment: The answer below is showing the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can an SQL query return data from multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT c.courseId, c.courseName, p.prereqId, pc.courseName
FROM course as c
     // joins prerequisites
     LEFT JOIN prereq as p on p.courseId=c.courseId
     // joins course data to prerequisites
     LEFT JOIN course as pc on p.prereqId=pc.courseId
```

Comment: yesss...   it works. thank yo very much :)))

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a left [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) to pull these two tables together, something like:

```
Select c.courseid, c.coursename, p.prere1id, p.preqname 
from course as c 
left join prereq as p 
on c.courseid = p.courseid
```

Comment: there's no prereqname , i think the prereq name is using the coursename.

Comment: I don't know your table scheme you didn't include it. In your expected output you have `Prereq Name`, change the column name(s) accordingly?

Comment: the table is there, table course = courseid, coursename, table prereq = courseid, prereqid.

Comment: You have `Prereq Name` in your output...

Comment: yes. but maybe the prereq name output is using the course name by looking the prereq id which is the same as courseid.If the prereq id is 1 then the course id is 1 too so the prereq name is intro into biology. can i use the coursename to do that?

Comment: You should post your whole scheme. It's hard to tell what you currently are doing. The SQL isnt just going to select something that isnt there though.